# Echo many arrays with "foreach"

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have arrays like that:

```
[mounts] => Array
                (
                    [collected] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Chauffeured Mekgineer's Chopper
                                    [itemId] => 120968
                                    [qualityId] => 7
                                    [icon] => inv_misc_key_06
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => Albino Drake
                                    [itemId] => 44178
                                    [qualityId] => 4
                                    [icon] => ability_mount_drake_blue
                            )
```

I need the [name] [itemId] [qualityId] [icon] of every array (they are numerated [0]-[xy]

Edited code:

```
$array = array('name'=>'xy','server'=>'frostwolf','fields'=>'mounts,stats');
    $type = 'character';
    $r = $client->fetch($type,$array);
    echo '<pre>';

    <?php  foreach($r['result']['mounts']['collected'] as $item)  { ?>
            <div class="summary-inventory-simple">
                <a href="//de.wowhead.com/item=<?php print $item['itemId']; ?>" class="<?php print $item['qualityId']; ?>">
                    <div class="iconmedium">
                        <img src="http://wow.zamimg.com/images/wow/icons/large/<?php print $item['icon']; ?>.jpg" alt="some_text" />
                </a></div>
        <?php }  ?>

    echo '</pre>';
```

I know this should be possible with foreach, but can´t get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($yourArr['mounts']['collected'] as $item) {
   $item['name]; 
   $item['other_key_what_you_need...']; ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are...

```
<?php  foreach($r['result']['mounts']['collected'] as $item)  { ?>
        <div class="summary-inventory-simple">
            <a href="//de.wowhead.com/item=<?php print $item['itemId']; ?>" class="<?php print $item['qualityId']; ?>">
                <div class="iconmedium">
                    <img src="http://wow.zamimg.com/images/wow/icons/large/<?php print $item['icon']; ?>.jpg" alt="some_text" />
            </a></div>
    <?php }  ?>
```

ps. I dont know why you used $r['result'] instead of $r['mounts'] ...

Comment: There is the [result] array over the [mounts] array, i just didn´t copied it. I tried your code, but i dont get it to work. I´ve updated my initial post. I don´t understand the <?php and <?php }  ?>. Do I need them at these positions?

Comment: can you elaborate what do you mean by you can't get it to work? what result did you get?

Comment: if the code doesn't work you should first check if your $r has fetched the data